# Combination of word as a autocomplete suggest once that word is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a paragraph which text I am splitting and creating an array which is later passed to jQuery autocomplete. It's working fine, but what I want is once I select a word and pressed space bar, the next word or (words) to the selected word should be suggested by autocomplete. Is it possible?

This is my current code:

```
var curDocParaText = $('.docTextFull').text();
var docWords = curDocParaText.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(" ");

$( "#parameter" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(req, responseFn) {
                var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
                var a = $.grep( docWords, function(item,index){
                    return matcher.test(item);
                });
                responseFn( a );
            }
});
```

This is working but I don't know what to do next to achieve what I want. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any words to the autocomplete suggestion by pushing them to the suggestion array (`a` in your code). So what you would need to do is:

1. Check if the last character is a blank space.
2. If it is, get the last word from the `#parameter` input.
3. Search that word in the list of words that you use as source (`docWords`).
4. If it is in the source, add the next word to the suggestion.

A simple demo would be something like this (that would be added to your function before the `responseFn( a );` part):

```
// get the value in the input
var textValue = $("#parameter").val();

// if the last character is a space
if (textValue.slice(-1) == " ") {

    // get the last word in the sentence
    var start = textValue.lastIndexOf(" ", textValue.length-2);
    var lastWord = textValue.substring(start + 1, textValue.length-1);

    // check if the word is in the source list
    var pos = docWords.indexOf(lastWord);
    if (lastWord != " " && docWords.length > pos) {

        // if it is, suggest the next word too as a sentence
        a.push($("#parameter").val() +docWords[pos+1]);
    }
}
```

Notice that this is really basic example, it doesn't check for word duplicates, or case, or anything else. You would need to extend it to make it more "complete" and adjust it to your needs.

---

Here is a running demo:

```js
var curDocParaText = $('.docTextFull').text();
var docWords = curDocParaText.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(" ");
$( "#parameter" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(req, responseFn) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
        var a = $.grep( docWords, function(item,index){
            return matcher.test(item);
        });
        
        
        var textValue = $("#parameter").val();
        if (textValue.slice(-1) == " ") {
            var start = textValue.lastIndexOf(" ", textValue.length-2);
            var lastWord = textValue.substring(start + 1, textValue.length-1);
            var pos = docWords.indexOf(lastWord);
            if (lastWord != " " && docWords.length > pos) {
                a.push($("#parameter").val() +docWords[pos+1]);
            }
        }
        
        responseFn( a );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div><b>Demo Sentence:</b></div>
<div class="docTextFull">"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"</div>
<hr/>
<input type="text" id="parameter">
```

Comment: actually the indexOf(lastWord) was taking first word found in the string and was suggesting next word from there which was inaccurate. Though I found the solution for it, thanks for showing the way.